# User Login session variable filtered

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to compare a session variable to another string so that i can enable or disable image buttons. I am using asp.net vb with a sql2005 express backend

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim string1 As String
    Dim string2 As String

    Label1.Text = Session("Username")
    Label2.Text = Session("UserId")

    string1 = Session("Username")
    string2 = "medev"

    If String.Compare(string1, string2, True) = 1 Then
        ImageButton1.Enabled = False

    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is works!

```
    ImageButton1.Enabled = Not Session("UserName") Is Nothing AndAlso Session("UserName").ToString.ToLower.Trim.Equals("username")
```

ImageButton2.Enabled = Not Session("UserName") Is Nothing AndAlso_ Session("UserName").ToString.ToLower.Trim.Equals("username")

Answer (score 1):

String.Compare returns `-1`, `0` or `1` depending on the result:

```
String.Compare("A", "B", true) ' returns -1 '
String.Compare("B", "A", true) ' returns 1 '
String.Compare("B", "B", true) ' returns 0 '
```

In your case, `ImageButton1` will be disabled if the user name would come before "`medev"` if you sorted them as a list. So `"Adam"` wound have it disabled, while `"Stuart"` would have it enabled. `"medev"` would also get it disabled, because if the strings are equal, String.Compare returns `0`. My guess is that you want `ImageList1` enabled for `"medev"`:

```
If String.Compare(string1, string2, True) <> 0 Then
    ImageButton1.Enabled = False
End If
```

I would also suggest using the [`String.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx) overload that takes a [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) instead of a bool to get a case insensitive compare. In my opinion it makes it a lot easier to understand what the code does:

```
If String.Compare(string1, string2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) <> 0 Then
    ImageButton1.Enabled = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

String Compare returns 0 if the strings are equal. To evaluate for true change your comparison to = 0 rather than <> 0.

```
If String.Compare(string1, string2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0 Then
```

If you envision performing such checks frequently to display different portions of a page you might want to break your pages up based on the different types (or levels) of users you expect and redirect them to a particular page upon login. Depending on how similar the pages are between users you'll likely find using [master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) and/or [user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) to be beneficial.

Comment: oh i understand now i didn't notice the add comment section so i asked the question again..thanks...Ok this is how my problem started..i wanted to build a space in which i can display pictures of a project in it's different stages i pull the rest of the information associated with the customer from a sql2005 exp DB..because i was unable to display the pics associated with the specific user dynamical i chose to have a list of image buttons on a secure page which would represent different clients i would like these buttons to enable or disable based on the passes session(userid)..