# dissable image buttons

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User Login session variable filtered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162114/user-login-session-variable-filtered)

I am trying to compare a session variable to another string so that i can enable or disable image buttons. I am using asp.net vb with a sql2005 express backend.

I was  using string.compare to compare the session variable sent from the login page to a string I set to "medev" which is a username in my database, if the condition is true and username "medev" is found I would like to disable some image buttons.  Can someone show me how to fix my code or a way to do this? Rhanks!

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim string1 As String
Dim string2 As String

Label1.Text = Session("Username")
Label2.Text = Session("UserId")

string1 = Session("Username")
string2 = "medev"


    If String.Compare(string1, string2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) < > 0 Then

        ImageButton1.Enabled = False

        MsgBox("Retrieved variable from masterpage is: " & Session("Username"))

    End If
```

Comment: It seems you've asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162114/user-login-session-variable-filtered - rather than ask a new question you should keep up with your original and ask the people who answered for clarification if you still need help.